# Make image positioned on other element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I need to make image positioned like on below picture:

[image]

I have code:

```
<footer>
    <div class="stopka1">
        <div class="container">
            ....................
            </p>
            <a href="#top"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="padding-right:0; padding-left:0;padding-top:30px;padding-bottom:20px;">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="phone.png" style="vertical-align:middle !important;"> <span style="font-weight:lighter;color:rgb(10, 55, 110);font-size: 28px; vertical-align:middle !important;">22 213 18 31</span></div>
                <div class="col-xs-6"><a href="" style="width:100%;"><button class="col-cs-12 przycisk-pytanie" style="font-weight: bold;margin-top:0;">Zadaj pytanie</button></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="women.png" style=""></div>
                <div class="col-xs-5">.. price ..</div>
                <div class="col-xs-5"><a href="" style="width:100%;"><button class="przycisk-rezerwuj-big" style="font-weight: bold;height:35px;">Rezerwuj teraz</button></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Have someone any idea how to get this effect? I have no idea how to force it to cover higher div.

Comment: Either negative margin or relative positioning...depending on the effect you are going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two options:

**OPTION 1**

```
img {margin-top:-20px;}
```

**OPTION 2**

```
img {position:relative; top:-20px;}
```

Comment: Thanks. That has helped.